# change directory without a shell in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Within a bash script, I would like to `chroot` to a directory and `cd` to another subdirectory immediately there after.  I would like to do this via `exec chroot [dir] cd [subdir]`, but I get a file not found error.  This is because the `cd` command in not in the new directory tree.  The `cd` command is normally provided by a shell, but I need to avoid starting a child process with eval.

Is there a way to change directory without requiring a shell in linux?  I looked for packages containing `cd` in linux, but coreutils does not contain it.  Thank you.

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in command. Its function cannot be performed by an external program, so there's no such program and no package that contains one.

Comment: As @n.m. points out, this may not be possible. What is the reason you need to `cd`, perhaps we can obviate the need to execute it.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense. Even if you _could_ run `exec chroot [dir] cd [subdir]`, you'd be back in your old directory as soon as it exited, as directory changes (like environment changes) are only accessible to subprocesses.

Comment: I guess the question makes sense if he wants to run some command in the chroot in a given working directory. If he doesn't have a shell in the chroot environment, how is he going to achieve this? It would be handy if the chroot command itself provided such an option, but at least mine doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Yes, as Jester pointed out, I want to run a command within the working directory.  So the command in its entirety would be: exec chroot [dir] cd [subdir] [command]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `schroot` program/package. That seems to have an option to change diretory:

```
-d, --directory=directory
    Change to directory inside the chroot before running the command or login shell.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `cd` program. `cd` is a builtin to your shell; it makes the shell change its own current directory. Processes can't change the current directory of other processes, so there is no `cd` program possible (it would run in another process and have no effect to the calling process).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wish chroot itself had the option to change directories.